# Is it possible to embed a jar file inside a flex application?

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, jar, embed

I have a great idea and I want to build a flex application around a .jar file. Is there a way I can go by embedding a jar file into the flex application?

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to [embed](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_3.html) assets into a Flex application, however most people use this for images or other visual assets.  I do not believe that jar is supported.  Java and ActionScript are very different and you wouldn't be able to load a jar inside the flash player and execute it as a program or run commands against it.

If this is an AIR application, you may be able to do something using [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html).  But, such an approach is not the same as embedding a jar file in a Flex Application.  It is taking your file and wrapping it up in an AIR installer and then communicating with that file as it runs natively on the machine.

Comment: Thanks are usually better expressed by adding up-votes to an answer and/or marking it correct.  ;)